# How to use an object as an argument in JavaScript subclasses?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, subclass

For example, if I have something like this:

```
class X{
    constructor({one, two}){
        this.one = one 
        this.two = two
    }
}

class Y extends X{
    constructor(props, three){
        super(props)
        this.three = three
    }
}
```

And I want to create an object with:

```
console.log(new Y({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}))
```

Is it possible? I tried other ways like:

```
console.log(new Y({one: 1, two: 2}, 3))
console.log(new Y({one: 1, two: 2}, {three: 3}))
```

but they are uncomfortable.

Comment: Use `this.three = props.three`. Do not add a second parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that...
[simply use Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
class X {
  constructor({one, two}) {
    this.one = one 
    this.two = two
  }
  displaying() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

class Y extends X {
  constructor({three, ...OneTwo}) {
    super(OneTwo)
    this.three = three
  }
}

let zz = new Y({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3})

zz.displaying()
```

Comment: Good answer! Slight correction of a bug In your first example, though.   You also need to add `three`  as a second parameter in  class Y's constructor:  `constructor(props, three)`.  Additionally, rather than using props in the first example, you can destructure variables `one` and `two` like this: `constructor ({one, two}, three)` and then you don't need dot notation when calling `super`

Comment: oops, looks like I ran out of time to finish editing my first comment.  Meant to add that if you wanted to make the parameter one object like the way you called it, then you could also destructure the `three` instead of passing as a separate parameter and using it as its own variable.

Comment: @hoekma you're right, my first example was wrong and unnecessarily complicated